# Is there a generic way of accessing a container of mutable elements?

Tags: rust

I would like to mutate elements in a container. The only thing I care about is the length of the container and the fact that the container's elements are ordered (i.e. there is a first element, a second element, etc.). But I'm struggling to do this.

My first attempt was to use an `Iterator` of mutable references:

```
fn mutate<'a, A, I>(items: I) where I: Iterator<&'a mut A>
```

The problem is that I need to iterate more than once over the elements. But to avoid aliasing mutable references, structs like `Slice`'s `IterMut` don't implement `Clone` or `RandomAccessIterator`. So as far as I know, I can't use the same iterator to iterate over mutable references more than once.

So then I looked at the `IndexMut` trait. This seems to be what I want, but I can't find another trait that specifies the length of a container. And the `Slice` struct that implements `IndexMut` does bounds checking for each access, which is undesirable.

So is there a way to do what I want? It would be nice to use `Iterator`s, since what I really want to do is to iterate over the mutable elements several times.

Comment: How generic do you need it to be? Do you have a sample of types you need to support?

Comment: I'd like to support as many types as possible, but I'm mostly looking to support slices and circular buffers (RingBuf).

Answer (score 1):

You can require more bounds:

```
fn mutate<'a, A, I>(items: I) 
where I: Iterator<Item=&'a mut A>,
      I: ExactSizeIterator,
      I: RandomAccessIterator,
      I: Clone {
```